# Не работает функция str_replace на php

Tags: php, html, form

Здравствуйте.

Помогите найти ошибку в коде.

Есть два текстовых поля. При вводе определённого слова в первом поле и нажатии enter должна производиться замена исходного слова на новое во втором текстовом поле.

На этот код

```
<?
    $b = '';
    if(isset($_POST['a'])){
        $b = $_POST['a'];

    }
?>

<?
$s = $b
$s = str_replace("привет", "пока");

$b = $s
?>

<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<body>
<br>
В первое текстовое поле введите запрос. Нажмите кнопку "отправить". 
<br><br>
<form method="post">
<input type='text' size="100" name='a'><br>
<input type='text' size="100" name='b' value='<?=$b?>'> 
<input type='submit' value="Отправить">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

выводится ошибка

```
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$s' (T_VARIABLE) in ...test.php on line 11.
```

11 строка это код "$s = str_replace("привет", "пока");"

Пытался другой код использовать:

заменил этот код

```
$s = str_replace("привет", "пока");
```

на

```
if (strpos($s, 'привет') !== false) {
$s = str_replace("привет", "пока", $s);
}
```

Выводит ошибку "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in ...test.php on line 11"

11 линия это "if (strpos($s, 'привет') !== false) {"

Где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: вы ; теряете. например тут $s = $b и в других местах тоже вот он и ругается. а реплейс не при делах. это не руби, тут они нужны

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Правильно пишет, третьего параметра нет:
str_replace ( "что ищем", "на что меняем", "где" )

```
$s = str_replace("привет", "пока", $s);
```

Comment: Ну и точки с запятой не забывайте

Answer (score 0):

Если добавить точку с запятой и третий параметр, то в браузере `Opera 12.17` всё прекрасно работает. А в `IE 11` и в браузере `Vivaldi` не отображается кириллица, и замена не происходит.